# Eclipse Scout Neon Focus inside rows after import data

Tags: import, cell, eclipse-scout, lost-focus

I have some dependencies hierarchy on my form, so I implemented hierarchy check on server side of the scout. If one field is changed, it triggered check if other need to be changed as well. This is done with export/import form data.

```
MyFormData input = new MyFormData();
FormDataUtility.exportFormData(this, input);
input = BEANS.get(IMYService.class).validate(input, field);
FormDataUtility.importFormFieldData(this, input, false, null, null);
```

validate function change all other fields that need to be changed.

My problem is with editing cells in editable tables.

If I change value in cell, and this chain validation is triggered, after importing form data I lose focus in cell. So instead, tab will move me to another cell, tab trigger import and focus in cells are lost. And this is a really bad user experience.

How to fix this?
How to stay in focus (of next cell) after import has been called?

Marko

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this applies for you, but you can try the following:

I assume, that you do your export/validate/import logic in the `execCompleteEdit(ITableRow row, IFormField editingField)` of your column class. I suggest, that you calculate your next focusable cell by yourself and request its focus after importing the form data. 

As an example, you can do this like that:

```
    @Override
    protected void execCompleteEdit(ITableRow row, IFormField editingField) {
       super.execCompleteEdit(row, editingField);
       // create form data object
       // export form data
       // call service and validate
       // import form data
       // request focus for next cell
       focusNextAvailableCell(this, row);
    }
```

with `focusNextAvailableCell(this, row)` as following:

```
private void focusNextAvailableCell(IColumn<?> col, ITableRow row) {
    if (col == null || row == null) {
        return;
    }
    IColumn<?> nextColumn = getColumnSet().getColumn(col.getColumnIndex()+1);
    ITableRow nextRow = getTable().getRow(row.getRowIndex());
    if (nextColumn == null) {
        // no next column (last column lost focus)
        // check if next row is available
        nextRow = getTable().getRow(row.getRowIndex()+1);
        // maybe select first cell again?
        if (nextRow == null) {
            nextColumn = getColumnSet().getColumn(0);
            nextRow = getTable().getRow(0);
        }
    }

    if (nextColumn != null && nextRow != null) {
        getTable().requestFocusInCell(nextColumn, nextRow);
    }
}
```

You should be aware, that you have to call this after every form data import in your `execCompleteEdit` method of your column. Also this is triggered not only when switching cells through pressing the tab key, but also when clicking with the mouse button.

Best regards!

Comment: This is not ok for me because of your last comment. execCompleteEdit is triggerend always when leav the cell. In this case I can't select another field in form because focus will be returned to next cell. Is it possible to remember current focus. If I understand super.execCompleteEdit(row, editingField); should move focus to the next cell or to another field, so after import this field should be focused again.

Comment: You could save the currently focused cell into a member variable. For example, you could register a listener on the table (org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ui.basic.table.TableListener), listen to TableEvent.TYPE_REQUEST_FOCUS_IN_CELL events and save currently focused cell.

Comment: This could be ok, but I don't know how to set listener for TableEvent.TYPE_REQUEST_FOCUS_IN_CELL. Right now in fireTableEventInternal TYPE_ROWS_SELECTED is fired.

Comment: Ok. I just saw, that only AbstractTable.requestFocusInCell(IColumn<?>, ITableRow) triggers a fireRequestFocusInCell(...) event, which finally allows you to listen to TableEvent.TYPE_REQUEST_FOCUS_IN_CELL. If you don't call requestFocusInCell in AbstractTable manually, you won't get TYPE_REQUEST_FOCUS_IN_CELL events fired (at least I didn't). But instead, you could save the currently focused cell in AbstractColumn.execPrepareEdit(ITableRow) or in AbstractColumn.execCompleteEdit(ITableRow, IFormField). But you have to override it in every single column...

Comment: This is not working for me, because AbstractColumn.execPrepareEdit is not called on next cell because it is interrupted by form data import.